Variant of Submodular Optimization
For variants of submodular optimization, I have seen many works on
$$\min_{P\in S} |P| \quad s.t.\quad  f(P)>q,$$ where f is submodular.
What I really need is the form of $$\max_{P\in S} |P|  \quad s.t.\quad f(P)<q.$$
Can anyone kindly share some works along this line?
Thank you so much!
